# Can UTF-8 schema validate ISO-8859-2 xml?

Tags: xml, encoding, xsd

Can XML schema encoded in UTF-8 validate some xml that is encoded in ISO-8859-2 or encoding must be the same ?

schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:....
```

data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-2"?>
<data>...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema and document encodings are entirely independent.